# Wrap fractional part of decimal in a span

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am printing a variable (called `something.price`) to a Haml template and its value is a string representation of a decimal with 2-digit precision. I want to wrap the fractional part of the decimal (including the `.`) in a `span`.

*Example:* If we have `"1234.41"`, we want to wrap the `span` around the `.41` part. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the format of your original string (decimal, two digit precision, etc.), you can wrap the decimal point portion of that string in a `<span>` by doing something like the following:

```
price  = '1234.41'
result = price.sub('.', '<span>.').concat('</span>')
# => "1234<span>.41</span>"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's works, yes! But i need showing `span` tag like a html/haml tag, not a text inside my element. Now my price showing on page `1234<span>.41</span>`

Comment: Oh god, I forgot about `.html_safe`. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert to string with to_str method if it's a number, then, use the .split method, something like this:

```
number = "1234.41"
```

then do something like this

`number.split(".")`

I ignore if you are doing this on backend or frontend, anyway you can find this split method on javascript. Once you have the array, you can iterate with the result.